# Why does an infrared thermometer work with a fixed emissivity?

Tags: thermal-radiation

I have a cheap infrared thermometer that works with a fixed emissivity of 0.95. My understanding is that the thermometer measures the amount of thermal radiation at some wavelength (range) and estimates the surface temperature from that.

What I don't understand is why that temperature is (more or less) accurate for different materials. For example, white paper has an emissivity around 0.7 and rubber has an emissivity around 0.95. I couldn't find out which wavelength my thermometer uses, so I'm guessing it's around 50 micrometers (mid infrared). Then I would expect the thermometer to display temperature differences >50° between paper and rubber for the same real surface temperature:

[image]

But in fact I get very similar measurements. (Less than 5°C differences between all materials I could find)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an object has low emissivity, it will have higher reflectivity.  If all you're measuring are room temperature objects in a larger space at room temperature, then I wouldn't expect to see much difference.  Some of the energy the meter is reading is reflected IR.

Now if you warm the objects above ambient, I would expect the lower emmissivity object to show a temperature below the actual temperature.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So the emitted energy is actually $\text{Emissivity} * \text{Planck Radiation}(\text{surface temperature}) + (1-\text{Emissivity}) * \text{Planck Radiation}(\text{ambient temperature})$